# How to search for a commit in Git?

Tags: git

I want to search for a specific commit in all the branches I have in my repo. Thing is i have probably deleted or renamed the brach but I have the commit number. Can some one write me a git line that i can use to search for a specific commit in all the branches?
Thanks

Comment: What information are you looking for? What branch the commit is in (`git branch --contains <commit>)`? The contents of the commit (`git show <commit>`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by `commit number` you mean the `sha` number then a simple `git show <sha_number>` will show you the commit content.